# WinJS/ Windows Phone HTML and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, windows-store-apps, windows-phone, winjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a good case for trying to integrate Twitter Bootstrap ([v3 RC1](http://www.getbootstrap.com) at the time of writing) with a Windows Store WinJS app or even a Windows Phone HTML5 App?

It strikes me that the mobile first/ responsive nature of Bootstrap would lend itself well to rending in full screen mode and snapped view mode alike - in the case of a Windows Store App.

Given the traction Bootstrap is gaining each day, would it be worth attempting?

I can see that being able to use themes from places like [{wrap} bootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/) and [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/), to name a few, would be incredibly useful - especially if you're trying to create a consistent brand across web and devices.

An issue may well be how it would work with the panorama-like components...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends.

If you want more custom experience in your  app and not use WinJS too much I think it could be worth it, especially when win 8.1 comes out and all apps will have to work and scale from 500px width to large widths of desktop monitors (no more snapped mode).

If you want to fit in into win 8 UX guidelines I think Twitter Bootstrap would be more of a problem than help.

Microsoft has developed quite extensive set of UX guidelines from [laying out the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872191.aspx), margins, font sizes to animations etc.

They did this so most of win store apps should present familiar to user patterns (bottom app bar, search etc).

You can read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh770552. Those guidelines are quite detailed and worth reading.

Twitter bootstrap doesn't really fit those guidelines so you would have to hack it a lot to adjust to them.

Additionally if you're using WinJS you also need to be familiar and use WinJS css 'framework' (ui.dark.css or ui.light.css) to style WinJS controls. More controls you use more it's css framework you need to learn & tweak. Many of those controls are designed to scale from small to large widths (listview, appbar etc.) so you get it for free.

Trident engine in IE10/11 (where you app runs) has very good support for [grid layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [flexbox layout](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) what ease making responsive designs in great way. It also supports many custom '-ms' extensions to css when it comes to zooming/panning via touch/mouse or keyboard which twitter bootstrap doesn't support.

You can always grab only pieces from Bootstrap you need and ignore the rest. 
Just remember that one of win store app requirements is that app must be  fully accessible via keyboard/mouse and touch, so make sure that boostrap components work well with touch.

Comment: Good answer. So much of the advantage of a lot of the big web libraries is in the abstracting away of the many browsers, which becomes a moot point when you're targeting Windows 8. It seems to me that a good design strategy is to take a dependency on something like bootstrap for your web views and take a dependency on WinJS for your Windows 8 views, but then create some style sheets (of mostly class rules likely) that tie the two together thematically. Put your colors in there, your custom fonts, etc.

Comment: Well I guess the intent is to create a cross platform app, as windows allows HTML5 + CSS. Unfortunatelly, windows apps have to rely on WinJS and all other dependencies from microsoft ( like custom tags & etc ) that it makes it way harder to make the same app work on other environments, e.g. Firefox OS or Android